# Change date format on pandas visulaisation on x axis

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization

Hello I am trying to change the format of my date on a graph i have created through pandas but not sure how. Currently it shows the date as just year but i would like to show the year-month.

No idea how and its driving me nuts!

For context, the graph is showing stock prices from Tesla, General Motors and Ford over a period  from 2015 to 2020. Ive attached a screenshot of the graph too, and the code im using to generate the graph.

tesladf (Tesla), gmdf (General Motors), and fdf (Ford) are the variables of the dataframes ive created earlier in the code.

Here is the the code im using to generate the dataframe from pandas datareader (this is just for Tesla. I have done the same for General Motors and Ford):

```
tesladf = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'yahoo', start, end).drop(columns=['Adj Close'])
tesladf.head()
```

This then produces the following dataframe showing the top 5

[Image of Tesla data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40KoS.png)

Here is my code where im generating the plot graph:

```
tesladf['Open'].plot(label='Tesla',figsize=(16,8),title='Open Price',)
gmdf['Open'].plot(label='GM')
fdf['Open'].plot(label='Ford')
plt.margins(0)
plt.legend()
```

[Image of plotted graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf77x.png)

As you can see on the x axis, the date is just the YYYY (year), I want to be YYYY-MM (year and month).

Thanks
Sunny

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please share a sample of your data so we may understand how your error happens.

Comment: Hi, ive attached a screenshot of the graph 'Image of plotted graph'. The sample data is loaded through a datareader from an external website which produces a dataframe in jupyter. I can show you a screenshot of that dataframe if you like?

Comment: 1. How do the dates look like in you df (format)?
 2. What is the dtype your dates?

Comment: I have just edited my original comment where you can now see the code im using to create the dataframe and the image of the dataframe. The dates in the dataframe look like YYYY-MM-DD